# Using data from my cartodb in my search box

Tags: carto, carto-js

I would like to use the data on my cartodb in the search function using SQL API. Please help me understand what is missing form my code because when i use my search, i get this error:-

> (Bad Request)send @ cartodb.js:5ajax @ cartodb.js:5a.execute @
>   cartodb.js:23a.getBounds @ cartodb.js:23(anonymous function) @
>   cartoEx2.html:66dispatch @ cartodb.js:4h @ cartodb.js:4

My code is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<style>
  html, body,#map {
      width:100%; 
      height:100%; 
      padding: 0; 
      margin: 0;

    }
  div#searchbox{
    background-color: #d2eaef;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9000;

    }
    div#searchbox input{
      width: 200px;
    }
    div#results{
      background: #FFF;
    }
 </style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />

  </head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="searchbox">
  <input type="text" name="ad" value="" id="ad" size="10" />
  <button type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>

<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
<script>
  var layer;
  var input;
  var map;
  function main() {

    var map = L.map('map', { 
              zoomControl: false,
              center: [-29.436487, 24.854498],
              zoom: 6
            });
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'}).addTo(map);

    // add CartoDB layer
        cartodb.createLayer(map,'https://nomcebo-geoilocate.carto.com/api/v2/viz/6b67556c-a25e-11e6-b8e7-0e05a8b3e3d7/viz.json').addTo(map)
        .done(function(){
          $('#searchButton').click(function(){
            input = $( "#ad").val();
            console.log(input);
            var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'nomcebo-geoilocate' });
             sql.getBounds("SELECT * FROM ecngo_members where name Ilike '" + input + 
             "'").done(function(bounds) {
                 // console.log(bounds);
             map.fitBounds(bounds)
            });

          });
        });
  }

  window.onload = main;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, there is no `name` field in the `ecngo_members` dataset. So I recommend changing `name` to one of the existing fields, such as `town`. On the other hand, because your dataset contains points instead of polygons I would add `map.setZoom(13);` just after `map.fitBounds(bounds);`.